# Amazon S3 check object metadata before delete

Tags: php, api, file-upload, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

When my app users upload files to S3 I add a metadata in the object with the user id.

e.g. `x-amz-meta-user_id = 9`

I allow my users to delete their files in the php app:

```
$response = $s3->delete_objects ($bucket, array(
            'objects' => $array //objects to be deleted
));
```

Before deleting an object is it possible to check if the user id metadata in S3 matches the user id in my app? This would add extra security not allowing users to delete another user's files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP SDK, use the [`AmazonS3::get_object_headers()`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/get_object_headers) method to look for the `x-amz-meta*` header of your choice and compare it to the current user.

If you have a match, do ahead and execute the delete.

Comment: Thanks! There's also a `get_object_metadata()` method http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/get_object_metadata

Comment: This is true. But `get_object_metadata()` has to make multiple network calls to collect all of its data. We've made it more efficient by leveraging batch requests, but the trade-off is that `get_object_metadata()` itself can't be batched. `get_object_headers()` is a single network call that _can_ be batched, and still provides the data relevant to this particular issue. :)

Comment: For anyone who comes across this, the correct method now seems to be `headObject` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_headObject